# Visual Studio code not connecting directories/references from imported packages

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide

Usually with an IDE, when the Python interpreter is set to the anaconda python.exe file, and the environment is correct, the imported packages can be easily referenced and the IDE will acknowledge them. But, I am getting no references to packages installed. The code runs, when I run the python package, but I cannot look back at where certain classes/functions/etc. come from.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Here is an image of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: I worked with that exact library some time ago and from what i remember, it had to do with how it wrapped the underlying C++ code for that library. Do you have that problem with your other packages or just the Pylon library?

Comment: Yea it is with every library/packages

Comment: Try following the instructions at this link:https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python 
Specifically; do you have the Python Extention installed? Do you have the Interpreter set? Those are gone over in that article so you can check.

Comment: Thanks that helped and it seems to work now.

Comment: If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension and [select the correct interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters).

[image]